# Find precisely the coefficients of product matrix AB as from B.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the book by Serge Lang, titled 'Introduction to Linear Algebra', there is given on pg. #88, as below:

> Let $A = (a_{ij}), B = (b_{jk})$ & let $AB =C$ with $C =(c_{ik})$. Let $C^k$ be the $k$-th column of $C$. Express $C^k$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Describe precisely which are the coefficients, coming from the matrix $B$.

Let us take an example with given size of matrices $A,B$, such that the sizes differ for all $3$ matrices; e.g. $A$ is a $2*3$ matrix, $B$ is a $3*2$ matrix; while their product is a $2*2$ one; while the terms are general ones.
I hope this will help understand the general case of matrices: $A$ of size $m*n$, $B$ of size $n*k$, $AB$ of size $m*k$.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}  & a_{13}\\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $, $B = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12}\\ 
b_{21} & b_{22}\\ 
b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{bmatrix} $, $C = AB = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22} + a_{13}b_{32}\\ 
a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} + a_{23}b_{31} & a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} + a_{23}b_{32}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

Let $k=2$ (out of the two possible values for $k=1,2$), for $C^2$ or the $2$-nd column of $C$, and follow the approach given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/534890/424260) to express as a linear combination of $A$.
Let us express the matrix $A$ in terms of columns only as : $A = \begin{bmatrix}
A^1 & A^2  & A^3\\ 
\end{bmatrix} $. So, for $C$ have $\begin{bmatrix}
A^1 & A^2 & A^3\\ 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12}\\ 
b_{21} & b_{22}\\ 
b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
C^1 & C^2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A^1 b_{11}+ A^2 b_{21}+ A^3 b_{31} & A^1 b_{12}+A^2 b_{22}+A^3 b_{32}
\end{bmatrix},$
with $C^2$ being the second term .

I feel tempted here (due to lack of clarity due to generalized terms) to consider a practical example of two linearly independent vectors $A,B$, with given dimensions. Taking actual value based example for $A,B$, get:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4\\ 
5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $, $B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
3 & 4\\ 
5 & 6
\end{bmatrix} $, $AB = \begin{bmatrix}
2\times 1 + 3\times 3 + 4\times 5 & 2\times 2 + 3\times 4 + 4\times 6\\ 
5\times 1 + 6\times 3 + 7\times 5 & 5\times 2 + 6\times 4 + 7\times 6\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
$AB = \begin{bmatrix}
2 + 9 + 20=31 & 4 + 12 + 24=40\\ 
5 + 18 + 35=58 & 10 + 24 + 42=76\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

Want verify the above expression $C^2$, for the given example with $A^1 = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 
5 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}, A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 
6 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}, A^3 = \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\ 
7 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$.

So, $C^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
A^1b_{12}+A^2b_{22}+A^3b_{32}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 
5 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\cdot 2 +  \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 
6 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\cdot 4 + \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\ 
7 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\cdot 6 $.

Although am clueless, yet follow the hint given [here at mse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683401/424260), even though my chosen matrix $A$ would not lead to an identity ($I$) matrix (*as, the $rref$ form works for rectangular matrices. But, it will 'only' produce leading row entry (left to right, across rows) as* $1$). 
Still would follow it to find $rref$ form of the augmented matrix $[A|AB]$, given as :
$[A|AB] = \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
a_{11} & a_{12}  & a_{13}&a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22} + a_{13}b_{32}\\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22} + a_{13}b_{32}\\ 
\end{array} $
which for the example at hand is:
$[A|AB] = \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
2 & 3 & 4 & 31 & 40\\ 
5 & 6 & 7 & 58 & 76\\ 
\end{array}\implies \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
2 & 3 & 4 & 31 & 40\\ 
0 & -1.5 & -3 & -19.5 & -24\\ 
\end{array}\implies \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
2 & 0 & -2 & -7 & -16\\ 
0 & -1.5 & -3 & -19.5 & -24\\ 
\end{array}\implies \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
1 & 0 & -1 & -7/2 & -8\\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 13 & 36\\ 
\end{array}$

Please help me with : (i) vetting for any error above, 
(ii) please tell if have expressed above $C^2$ correctly as a linear combination of $A$, 
 (iii) how to find out the coefficients coming from matrix $B$.

Comment: Why $A = \begin{bmatrix} c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13}\end{bmatrix}$? The $c_{ij}$ are the entries of $C=AB$ and $A$ is a $2\times 3$-matrix. Denote by $A^k$ the $k$-th column of $A$ (just like $C^k$ is the $k$-th column of $C$) and proceed.

Comment: @Christoph Hope my changes are complete and valid. Please give inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $A$ has $n$ columns $A^i$, $1\le i\le n$. We can then describe $A$ using the columns of $A$ thus: $A = \begin{bmatrix}A^{1} & A^{2}  & \dots & A^{j} \dots & A^{n}  \end{bmatrix}$. To multiply $A$ and $B$, $B$ necessarily has $n$ rows, and so the $k$th column of $C=AB$, or $C^k$, is formed by multiplying $A$ with the $k$th column of $B$, or $B^k$, thus
 $$
\begin{bmatrix}
A^{1} & A^{2}  & \dots & A^{j} \dots & A^{n} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1k}\\ 
b_{2k}\\ 
\vdots\\
b_{jk}\\
\vdots\\
b_{nk}\\
\end{bmatrix}=b_{1k}A^1+b_{2k}A^2+\dots+b_{jk}A^j+\dots+b_{nk}A^n\tag{1}$$

Only square matrices have the possibility of being invertible, so you can't row reduce to isolate $B$ in the non-square case.

Once you have a linear combination as in the left hand side of $(1)$ you can find the $b_{jk}$ entries of the $k$th column of $B$ by comparing with the original columns of $A$, *if* you know the $A^i$ first, i.e., if you already know $A$. For this consider your example: $A^1b_{12} = \begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 10 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, so $A^1=\frac{1}{b_{12}}\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 10 \\ \end{bmatrix}$. But you know $A^1 = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 10 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, so $b_{12}=2$ follows.

As to why $b_{ij}A^i=A^ib_{ij}$, $b_{ij}$ is a *scalar* here, and $A^i$ is a *column vector* so this is merely commutativity of multiplication of scalars thus: 
$$A^1b_{12} = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix}\cdot2=\begin{bmatrix}2\cdot2 \\ 5\cdot2 \\ \end{bmatrix}=2\cdot \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 5 \\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\cdot2 \\ 2\cdot5 \\ \end{bmatrix}=b_{12}A^1$$

Comment: Hope my actual value based $C^2$ representation in O.P.  is following your answer correctly. Please confirm.

Comment: Your $C^2$ is correct. Note when using $rref$ you need a square matrix to get the $B$ matrix via, $rref[A\mid AB] = [I\mid A^{-1}AB]=[I\mid B]$, as you noted. So can't see that helping you with the rectangular case. Once you have a linear combination as in the answer you can find the $b_{ij}$ coefficients by comparing with the original columns of $A$, i.e., $A^i$ with $b_{ij}A^i$, which should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. So, the problem is applicable only for square matrix $A$. Request some logic (proof) for the same that is more formal, and  states the dependence of $rref$ on squareness of $A$, & being independent of $B$. Also, request some expln. on reversal of ordering of product of $b_{jk}$ and $A^j$ matrices. I mean that why is matrix multiplication commutative here?

Comment: I edited the post as the comment went on too long. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Show that $C^k = AB^k$ using the definition of matrix multiplication. (Here $C^k$ and $B^k$ denote the $k$-th column of $C$ and $B$, respectively.)